# add incrimental dates in a dataframe by the condition in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, dplyr

Cheers, I have a data frames with the following structure.
Week_Start_Date is the start day of the week(Sunday).

```
DF1:
Week_Start_Date     Event              Days
2016-08-14          Independence       4
2016-01-24          Republic           3
```

I would like to alter DF1 (Increment the dates by a day till Days column). Eg: Independence is celebrated for 4 days staring from 2016-08-14 (Week_Start_Date) till 2016-08-17.

```
DF2:
Week_Start_Date     Event             Days
2016-08-14          Independence      1
2016-08-15          Independence      2
2016-08-16          Independence      3
2016-08-14          Independence      4
2016-01-24          Republic          1
2016-01-25          Republic          2
2016-01-26          Republic          3
```

I'm using 'dplyr' package and I tried, unsuccessfully, with:

```
DF2 <- rbind(DF1, DF1 %>% 
mutate(Week_Start_Date = Week_Start_Date + 1:Days, Event=Event, Days = 1:Days))
```

Can anyone point me to right direction?

Note:

```
str(DF1$Week_Start_Date): Date, format: "2016-08-04"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in base R:

```
# Sample data
DF1 <- cbind.data.frame(
    Week_Start_Date = c(as.Date("2016-08-14"), as.Date("2016-01-24")),
    Event = c("Independence", "Republic"),
    Days = c(4,3),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE);

# Apply per row, create list and rbind entries
lst <- apply(DF1, 1, function(x) 
    cbind.data.frame(
        Week_Start_Date = as.Date(x["Week_Start_Date"]) + seq(0, as.numeric(x["Days"]) - 1),
        Event = x["Event"],
        Days = seq(1, as.numeric(x["Days"])),
        row.names = NULL));
df <- do.call(rbind, lst);

# Output
print(df);
  Week_Start_Date        Event Days
1      2016-08-14 Independence    1
2      2016-08-15 Independence    2
3      2016-08-16 Independence    3
4      2016-08-17 Independence    4
5      2016-01-24     Republic    1
6      2016-01-25     Republic    2
7      2016-01-26     Republic    3
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Event` column doesn't contain duplicated values, you can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
       group_by(Event, Week_Start_Date) %>% 
       complete(Days = sequence(Days)) %>% 
       ungroup() %>% 
       mutate(Week_Start_Date = Week_Start_Date + Days - 1)

# A tibble: 7 x 3
#         Event Week_Start_Date  Days
#         <chr>          <date> <int>
#1 Independence      2016-08-14     1
#2 Independence      2016-08-15     2
#3 Independence      2016-08-16     3
#4 Independence      2016-08-17     4
#5     Republic      2016-01-24     1
#6     Republic      2016-01-25     2
#7     Republic      2016-01-26     3
```

More generally, if `Event` column contains duplicated values, you can create a row number as group variable, which can be done via the `tibble::rownames_to_column()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `data.table` after expanding the rows based on the value in 'Days'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$Days),])[,
   .(Week_Start_Date = Week_Start_Date + seq(.N)-1, Days = seq_len(.N)) , by = Event]
#          Event Week_Start_Date Days
#1: Independence      2016-08-14    1
#2: Independence      2016-08-15    2
#3: Independence      2016-08-16    3
#4: Independence      2016-08-17    4
#5:     Republic      2016-01-24    1
#6:     Republic      2016-01-25    2
#7:     Republic      2016-01-26    3
```